# Best fit from a set of curves to data points

Tags: python, performance, curve-fitting

I have a set of curves `F={f1, f2, f3,..., fN}`, each of them defined through a set of points, ie: I don't have the *explicit* form of the functions. So I have a set of `N` tables like so:

```
#f1: x  y
1.2  0.5
0.6  5.6
0.3  1.2
...

#f2: x  y
0.3  0.1
1.2  4.1
0.8  2.2
...

#fN: x  y
0.7  0.3
0.3  1.1
0.1  0.4
...
```

I also have a set of observed/measured data points `O=[p1, p2, p3,..., pM]` where each point has `x, y` coordinates and a given weight between `[0, 1]` , so it looks like:

```
#O: x  y  w
0.2  1.6  0.5
0.3  0.7  0.3
0.1  0.9  0.8
...
```

Since `N ~ 10000` (I have a big number of functions) what I'm looking for is an efficient (more precisely: **fast**) way to find the curve that best fits my set of observed and *weighted* points `O`.

I know how to find a best fit with `python` when I have the explicit form of the functions ([scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)), but how do I do that when I have the functions defined as tables?

Comment: "Best fit" doesn't have an obvious definition. The "efficient" criteria isn't terribly clear either - is a solution that is linear in the number of data points for each curve sufficient, or do you need something faster? Would it be OK to simply calculate the weighted sum of squared differences between each curve and each observation set maintaining that curve that yielded the minimum error as you go, or do you need something faster? Is weighted sum of squared errors the right definition of "best"?

Comment: Weighted sum of squared errors is what I was thinking of, yes.  By "efficient" I actually mean "fast". Considering that I have circa 100000 functions and almost 200 `O` sets, that gives about 2000000 iterations which is quite a lot. I need it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: You didn't specify what the role of the weights in the fit is.

Comment: @elyase I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The weights are there to indicate that a given point should have more importance in whatever scheme used to asses the "best fit" (see http://goo.gl/MdIO3V for example).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no algorithm that automatically fits any data with the "best" possible fit(let alone the weights constrain). You have to specify an underlying model for your data (Linear Model, Gaussian Process, SVRs). If you show a plot of your data we could help you but this is not a programming question.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I want. I don't want to find the best fit to a data set out of _nothing_, I do have the `N` functions that can be used and I just need to find the one that best (defined by least square for example) fits the data. Python does this but for explicitly defined functions and I'm wondering if there's a way to do it when the functions are given as tables.

Comment: You need two elements in order to have a fit, the data(which you already have) and a model space(Linear Models, Gaussian Process, Support Vector Regression). Python cannot guess the function, it can adjust parameters of a given function to the data, BUT you have to give the function in any case. What you have is a Machine Learning Problem not a fitting problem. See my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35552/discussion-between-elyase-and-gabriel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. This combines some of the comments on your original post, and @elyase's solution above. @elyase has provided one way to interpolate between the points you have for each function. Given that, and the definition of best fit being weighted sum of squares, I think the following does what you want:

```
# Here a model is an interpolated function as per @elyase's solution above
min_score = sys.float_info.max
best_model = None
for model in models:
    # data is an array of (x, y, weight) tuples
    score = 0.0
    for data_point in data:
        w = data_point[2]
        x = data_point[0]
        y = data_point[1]
        score += w * (y - model.get_y(x)) ** 2
    if score < min_score:
        best_model = model
return best_model
```

You mention that you need a "fast" solution. Based on your answers above, doing the above for each set of data results in about 2 million iterations total. That shouldn't be more than a few seconds, even with Python. Is that fast enough?

If not, things get much more complex. For example, you could try to store your models (you call them functions above) in sorted order such that `model1 > model2` if `model1(x) > model2(x)` for all `x` (given the interpolation thing above). That defines only a partial order, but that might be enough to be very helpful if your models have the right properties. Given that, you can do something akin to binary search. Alternatively, you could do a branch-and-bound thing where the bound is given by the distance between the first value in data and the first value in the function. Depending on the nature of your functions and data that might or might not help. There are solutions you could consider if you required an almost exact, but not necessarily optimal answer, etc., etc., etc. In short, to go beyond the trivial answer above, I think we need to know more about your time constraints, the data, and the models.

Answer (score 4):

You need two elements in order to have a fit, the data(which you already have) and a model space(Linear Models, Gaussian Process, Support Vector Regression). In your case your model has the additional constrain that some data points should be weighted differently than others. May be something like this works from you:

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

temp = np.asarray([10, 9.6, 9.3, 9.0, 8.7])
height = np.asarray([129, 145, 167, 190, 213])
f = UnivariateSpline(height, temp)
```

Now you can evaluate `f` wherever you want:

```
test_points = np.arange(120, 213, 5)  
plot(height, temp, 'o', regular_heights, f(test_points), 'x')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggested approach:

1. Place all functions in a single numpy array
2. Compute squared-distance between each point in your test data and each point in each function
   (you could also compute exact distance, but sqrt is expensive)
3. Compute error as weighted sum of distances (or modify this to your liking)
4. Find minimum error

For example:

```
import numpy as np

# define an array of N=3 functions
funcs = np.array([
    [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  # x1
     [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0]], # y1
    [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  # x2
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]], # y2
    [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  # x3
     [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]  # y3
    ], dtype=float)

# define the test data and weights with the same
# dimensions as function array
data = np.array([
    [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  # x
     [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]]  # y
    ], dtype=float)

weight = np.array([
    [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 0, 0]  # w
    ])

# compute distance between points in data and each function:
dist = ((funcs - data) ** 2).sum(axis=1)

# compute weighted error across all functions:
err = (dist * weight).sum(axis=1)

print "Errors:", err
print "Best fit:", np.argmin(err)
```

Comment: Luke this looks like a reasonable answer but it makes two strong assumptions I can not make: 1- the functions are not all defined by the same number of points (some have more and some less) and 2- the data points *definitely* do not have the same dimensions as the functions.

Comment: In that case, you could probably use scipy.interpolate.griddata to interpolate each function onto the data x-values, then proceed with the same distance/error calculation.